# Post-process multi-class predictions for image segmentation?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision

My FCN is trained to detect 10 different classes and produces an output of `500x500x10` with each of the final dimensions being the prediction probabilities for a different class.

Usually, I've seen using a uniform threshold, for instance `0.5`, to binarize the probability matrices. However, in my case, this doesn't quite cut it because the IoU for some of the classes increases when the threshold is `0.3` and for other classes it is `0.8`.

Hence, I don't have to arbitrarily pick the threshold for each class but rather use a more probabilistic approach to finalizing the threshold values. I thought of using CRFs but this also requires the thresholding to have already been done. Any ideas on how to proceed?

Example: consider an image of a forest with 5 different birds. Now im trying to output an image that has segmented the forest and the five birds, 6 classes, each with a separate label. The network outputs 6 confusion matrices indicating the confidence that a pixel falls into a particular class. Now, the correct answer for a pixel isnt always the class  with the highest confidence value. Therefore, a one size fits all method or a max value method won't work.

Comment: Could you be looking for *"Otsu Thresholding"* where you calculate the optimum threshold separating the two classes so that their combined spread (intra-class variance) is minimal... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method

Comment: There are 10 different classes, but the number of channels in your final output is 3 (`500X500` being `height X width`). Assuming each channel represents each class, won't it be `500X500X10` instead?

Comment: Yes you are right, i fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CRF Postprocessing Approch**

You don't need to set thresholds to use a CRF. I'm not familiar with any python libraries for CRFs, but in principle, what you need to define is:

1. A probability distribution of the 10 classes for each of the nodes
   (pixels), which is simply the output of your network.
2. Pairwise potentials: 10*10 matrix, where element Aij denotes the "strength" of the configuration that one pixel is of class i and the other of class j. If you set the potentials to have a value alpha (alpha >> 1) in the diagonal and 1 elsewhere, then alpha is the regularization force that gives you consistency of the predictions (if pixel X is of class Y, then the neighboring pixels of X are more likely to be of the same class).

This is just one example of how you can define your CRF.

**End to End NN Approach**

Add a loss to your network that will penalize pixels that have neighbors of a different class. Please note that you will still end up with a tune-able parameter for the weight of the new regularization loss.

Comment: But i dont see how i can reduce a 500x500x10 to a 500x500x1 matrix using otsu. Please correct me if im mistaken, but otsu segments an image into two groups, but if a pixel can belong to 10 different groups, and the class with the highest confidence values isnt always the correct one, then otsu wont work. Ive updated the question with an example

Comment: You're right - Otsu is for binary segmentation, which is why I suggested to treat it as 10 distinct binary segmentation tasks. But that was due to misunderstanding your question. The example clarified everything. Will try to update my answer accordingly.